# Desktop wakes from S3 sleep at random

Tags: suspend, power-management, 19.10, 20.04

My Ubuntu desktop won't stay in S3 sleep for more than a few hours before waking.  Sometimes it wakes immediately from sleep; sometimes it takes a few hours.  It's never stayed asleep for more than about 12 hours.

I have tried disabling *everything* in `/proc/acpi/wakeup` whilst also having *all* cables removed from the computer (except the power cable of course). It still wakes!  Wake-on-LAN is disabled in the BIOS settings.

This was an issue in Ubuntu 19.10 and continues to be an issue in 20.04.  I'm running the latest motherboard BIOS.

Please help!

[Here's the full dmesg output](https://gist.github.com/JackKelly/b47d930e0c710d1bbf9653017f986efa).  This shows the computer going into and out of sleep several times.  I think sleep starts with `PM: suspend entry (deep)`.  I think the system stars waking at the log line `ACPI: Low-level resume complete`

And [here's the full `/var/log/syslog` for one day](https://gist.github.com/JackKelly/e876dcbe1afab2898d04b372ae345a63).  I think suspend starts with [`May 11 11:04:14 jack-workstation NetworkManager[3354]: <info>  [1589191454.8204] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)`](https://gist.github.com/JackKelly/e876dcbe1afab2898d04b372ae345a63#file-syslog-L996) and the machine starts to wake with [`May 11 11:05:35 jack-workstation kernel: [73041.202770] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.003 seconds) done`](https://gist.github.com/JackKelly/e876dcbe1afab2898d04b372ae345a63#file-syslog-L1036)

The most suspicious line I can see in `syslog` is [`May 11 11:05:43 jack-workstation NetworkManager[3354]: <info>  [1589191543.4376] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)`](https://gist.github.com/JackKelly/e876dcbe1afab2898d04b372ae345a63#file-syslog-L1347)

Update: I've tried disabling network manager (`sudo service network-manager stop`).  The machine still wakes randomly.  [Here's the syslog](https://gist.github.com/JackKelly/b7a3e5b3d4fb99703770140e676b905c) when the machine went to sleep and woke randomly, after I disabled network manager and disabled everything in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`.

[Here's another syslog](https://gist.github.com/JackKelly/1320b9134419043a1d85d197923448dd), after I disabled network-manager, and put the machine to sleep for an hour and *manually* woke it after an hour.    The system went to sleep at 12:21:14 and I manually work it at 13:26:56

More syslogs where the machine work itself (even though everything in `/proc/acpi/wakeup` was disabled, as was network manager):

- [2020-05-13 syslog](https://gist.github.com/JackKelly/cd419cd6dc36d56edf41b378f1fbde33) - went to sleep around 12:12 and woke randomly at 13:08, maybe much earlier.
- [2020-05-13 syslog](https://gist.github.com/JackKelly/1926ad3b633bac8132e887eec5552d60) - asleep for 3 hr 21 min; from 20:44 to 00:05.

### System specs

- AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1900X 8-Core Processor
- Gigabyte X399 AORUS PRO motherboard (rev. 1.0)
- Nvidia RTX-2080Ti
- Seagate FireCude 510 1TB NVME SSD
- 8 x 12 TB Toshiba hard disks in ZFS raid-z2

### related forum threads & bug reports

- [System wakes from suspend without user initialization](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1811236) - fixed by disabling device in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`  (that doesn't work for me)
- [Wakes from suspend immediately when bluetooth device disconnected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089067/wakes-from-suspend-immediately-when-bluetooth-device-disconnected) - looks interesting but not sure it's relevant to my issue
- [After upgrade to Kubuntu 18.04, System wakes up immediately after suspend. Bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053319/after-upgrade-to-kubuntu-18-04-system-wakes-up-immediately-after-suspend-bug) - fixed by disabling device in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`  (that doesn't work for me)
- [Laptop wakes up by itself a few seconds after suspend or lidclose](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063030/laptop-wakes-up-by-itself-a-few-seconds-after-suspend-or-lidclose) - fixed by newer kernel

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's related but my desktop has started waking from S3 if any other device, such as a phone charger, is plugged/unplugged in the extension lead its powered from; no interaction with any button or device associated with the PC required!

That only started after upgrading to 20.04.